# How to extract the left most common characters in a string list?

Tags: java, string

Assume I have the following list of string objects:

```
ABC1, ABC2, ABC_Whatever
```

What's the most efficient way to extract the left most common characters from this list ? So I'd get **ABC** in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`StringUtils.getCommonPrefix(String... strs)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getCommonPrefix%28java.lang.String...%29) from Apache Commons Lang.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String commonInFirstTwo=greatestCommon("ABC1","ABC2");
    String commonInLastTwo=greatestCommon("ABC2","ABC_Whatever");
    System.out.println(greatestCommon(commonInFirstTwo,commonInLastTwo));
}

public static String greatestCommon(String a, String b) {
    int minLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
            return a.substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    return a.substring(0, minLength);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't behave correctly. For example, let the first string be "ABCABC" or "ACB".

Comment: Much better, but it would be quite simple to let the function take a list so you don't have to compose functions together.

Comment: The list could be variable in length.

Answer (score 0):

You hash all the substrings of the words in the given list and keep track of those substrings. The one with the maximum occurrences is the one you want. Here is a sample implementation. It returns the most common substring

```
static String mostCommon(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, Integer> word2Freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String maxFreqWord = null;
    int maxFreq = 0;
    for (String word : list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
            String sub = word.substring(0, i + 1);
            Integer f = word2Freq.get(sub);
            if (f == null) {
                f = 0;
            }
            word2Freq.put(sub, f + 1);
            if (f + 1 > maxFreq) {
                if (maxFreqWord == null || maxFreqWord.length() < sub.length()) {
                    maxFreq = f + 1;
                    maxFreqWord = sub;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return maxFreqWord;
}
```

The above implementation may not suffice if you more than one common substring. Use the map within it.

```
System.out.println(mostCommon(Arrays.asList("ABC1", "ABC2", "ABC_Whatever")));
System.out.println(mostCommon(Arrays.asList("ABCDEFG1", "ABGG2", "ABC11_Whatever")));
```

Returns

```
ABC
AB
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient way of solving this problem...you don't need the map and you don't need to keep creating substrings, just compare characters.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Comparing characters vs hashcode ? Did you understand the implementation ?

Comment: Yes, I understand it, and there are a lots of issues. Take a look at Ruchira's answer and see how it can generalize to a list. You don't need to go through the length of every string (in the average case), you don't need to create a ton of substrings, you don't need to compute hashcodes, you don't need the map.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Why don't you write an answer. It seems you have something interesting and faster than this.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind, and the simplest solution aside from a library call, is Ruchira's current answer. I would generalize it for a list but other than that it would identical.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a rephrase of the standard problem of finding the [longest common prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array)

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the common characters are, then you could check if the other strings contain those characters by using the .contains() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a third party library, then the following using [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) generates that prefix for you:

```
String prefix = Seq.of("ABC1", "ABC2", "ABC_Whatever").commonPrefix();
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ

Answer (score -1):

if there are N strings and the minimum length among them is M charterers, then the most efficient (correct) answer will take N * M at worst case (when all strings are same).

```
outer loop - each character of first string at a time
inner loop - each of the strings
test       - each charterer of the string in inner 
             loop against the charterer in outer loop.
```

the performance can be tuned upto (N-1) * M if we do not test against the first string in ther inner loop